# CARTO Mobile SDK.UWP (C#) Get always get current map's south-west MapPos and north-east MapPos

Tags: carto, c#, cartography

How can I always get the current map's south-west MapPos and north-east MapPos when I zoom in/zoom out the map or drag the map? I want to create a dynamic bounding box for Carto Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mapView.screenToMap` method with screen corner locations.  Here is Java sample, C# is practically same:

```
ScreenPos sp1 = new ScreenPos(0, mapView.getHeight() / 2);
ScreenPos sp2 = new ScreenPos(mapView.getWidth(), mapView.getHeight() / 2);
MapPos mp1 = mapView.screenToMap(sp1);
MapPos mp2 = mapView.screenToMap(sp2);
MapPos pos1Wgs = mapView.getOptions().getBaseProjection().toWgs84(mp1);
MapPos pos2Wgs = mapView.getOptions().getBaseProjection().toWgs84(mp2);
```